# Why does $\sigma = E\cdot\frac{\Delta l}{l} = E\cdot\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial z}$?

Tags: waves, solid-mechanics

When deriving the wave function ($\frac{\partial^2\xi}{\partial z^2}\left(z,t\right)=\frac{1}{c^2}\cdot\frac{\partial^2\xi}{\partial t^2}$) for longitudinal waves in a solid body we use Hooke's law $\sigma = E\cdot\epsilon = E\cdot\frac{\Delta l}{l}$ to determine the Force acting upon the cross section of the body. However, in my textbook (Experimentalphysik 1, Wolfgang Demtröder) Hooke's law is written as $\sigma = E\cdot\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial z}$ and I have no clue why $\epsilon = \frac{\Delta l}{l}$ should be equal to $\frac{\partial\xi}{\partial z}$. I would be very thankful if someone could explain this to me - if possible, as intuitively as possible.

Comment: What are $\xi$ and $z$ in this situation?

Comment: $\xi$ is the deviation from the equilibrium position at the time t and the location z where in this case z is the location of $\xi$ relative to the beginning of the solid body. Because it is a longitudinal wave, $\xi$ is in the direction of $\hat z$. Therefore it can also be written as $\vec\xi (z,t)=\hat z\cdot f(z,t)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Delta L$ is the difference in  the displacemnt of  points separated by distance  $L$. Similarly  $d\xi$ is is the difference in the displacement of  points separated by  $dz$. If the stretching were uniform the displacement  would be a linear function $\xi= \epsilon z$ of the difference, and the finite estimate ratio $\Delta L/L$  would equal  the infinitesimal ratio  $d\xi/dz$. This is just as the slope of a curve $y=mx+c$ is $m=(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$ or $m= dy/dx$.  For the waves the stretching is not uniform, so we have to use the derivative rather than the finite ratio $\Delta L/L$.

Comment: Please add the "/" in $=(2−1)/(2−1)$. An edit must be at least 6 characters long :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand the derivation much better now :) !